# How to compile java source files on the same package but on different folders

Tags: java, compilation, package

I am currently developing a Java program on Windows.

The file organization is as goes:

project

..|__ core

..........|__ Main.java

..........|__ Passenger.java

..........|__ Train.java

..|__ app

..........|__ RegisterPassenger.java

..........|__ LogTrain.java

Each of these files has the necessary "package ...;" notation.

However, all my attempts at compiling all the .java files have been frustrated and I can't seem to find any similar situations that have been solved. Any help appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Edit: I am building the project using only a text editor and the Windows command line

Comment: What do you mean by "my attempts have been frustrated"? Please post the full error message that you are getting

Comment: How is the code being built now?  I personally use maven exclusively to build my java projects, and maven is very strict on its directory structures.

Comment: We would need a [mcve]. You would have to include the commands you are using. We can't you what you are doing wrong when you do not tell us what you do.

Comment: @GBlodgett
I used the following command whilst on the folder previous to "project":
javac -cp d:\project\core Main.java
And this is the error message that I got:
javac: file not found: Main.java

Comment: @ash
Windows command line. I know there are some very useful tools out there but college makes us use only a text editor and a terminal :)